# Inserting data from a Exec clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any idea why I keep getting the error that `#temp2` is an invalid object?

I am trying to populate this table from a dynamic query that I am executing with `EXEC` command:

```
set @sql = 'Select DFRId, FiscalDate, Franchise_Number, Store_Number, Reviewer, '+@listStr+' from (Select DFRId, Reviewer, FiscalDate, Franchise_Number, Store_Number, Question, Score from #temp) as sourcetable Pivot (Max(Score) for Question in ('+@listStr+')) as pivotable order by Franchise_Number,Store_Number,FiscalDate  '

Insert #temp2 exec(@Sql)
```

Comment: Did you create #temp2? In order to insert into a temp table, you have to create it. It isn't like selecting into a temp table.

Comment: Not only that, but you are missing the word, "into".

Comment: `exec` will run the select statement - I don't think this is valid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

At first, make sure that your temporary table #temp2 is created.

Next, check the following code.

I hope your problem will be solved..

```
set @sql = 'INSERT INTO #temp2 
Select DFRId, FiscalDate, Franchise_Number, Store_Number, Reviewer, '+@listStr+' from (Select DFRId, Reviewer, FiscalDate, Franchise_Number, Store_Number, Question, Score from #temp) as sourcetable Pivot (Max(Score) for Question in ('+@listStr+')) as pivotable order by Franchise_Number,Store_Number,FiscalDate'

exec(@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors,  at first you must to include the into #temp2 clause before the FROM and inside the string. 
If you want to use the insert into #temp2, your table must to be defined previously